# CPanel Email Piping to PHP

Tags: php, cpanel, piping

I have created a pipe script in CPanel and have placed the hashbang:`#!/usr/bin/php -q` at the beginning of my script. The script does run and places a log of the email into a table in my DB as it should.

But...It sends an email back claiming that the email did not go through and appears as...

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

 pipe to |/home/xxxxx/xxxxx.php
   generated by support@xxxxxxx.net

The following text was generated during the delivery attempt:

------ pipe to |/home/xxxxxx/xxxx.php
      generated by support@xxxxxxxxx.net ------

PHP Deprecated:  Directive 'magic_quotes_gpc' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Deprecated</b>:  Directive 'magic_quotes_gpc' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
```

*I have removed all private information but nothing that is relevant to my issue.*

What could be my issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did you add the pipe in CPanel?

If you follow this guide: http://www.phpshare.org/articles/Piping-Incoming-Mail-with-PHP.html

It says to add the following into CPanel:

```
|php -q /home/phpshare/public_html/handler.php
```

Did you ALSO include the -q flag in CPanel as that guide describes?

Comment: FWIW nowadays this is out of date.  Cpanel says "If the script requires an interpreter such as Perl or PHP, you should omit the /usr/bin/perl or /usr/bin/php portion. Make sure that your script is executable and has the appropriate target at the top of the script."

Answer (score 1):

I think you must have upgraded your servers php version recently i.e 5.2.x to 5.3.

PHP 5.3 doesn't support `magic_quotes_gpc`.

So comment out or remove that line in php.ini. On cPanel server the path of php.ini is `/usr/local/lib/php.ini`

For commenting you should use `;`.

```
; magic_quotes_gpc = on
```

Answer (score 1):

if your php script fails for any reason (in this case the magic quotes error) your email gets rejected (even though you may have processed the email in your script).  The system "assumes" that if a script error occured then the message delivery failed.

As others have said, fix the magic quotes problem...

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and i found the answer here http://forums.kayako.com/threads/very-odd-piping-problem.11954/

The solution is to leave only one space break between **#!/usr/bin/php -q** and **<?php**:

Wrong way:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q

<?php
```

Right way:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
```